# mpo/mtp 12 and 100G

Tags: bandwidth, fiber

Does one mpo/mtp-12 fo can transmit 100G datas ?

I have doubt because of this picture :
[image]

It seems I need 24fo to get 100G. But I have a Cisco QSFP-100G-SR4-S module which says it can support 100G on a mpo-12.

What i'm missing ? Does someone can enlighten me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagram you provided is out of date.  One of the earlier standards, 100GBase-SR10 did use 24 fibers, but it's been replaced by a newer standard 100GBase-SR4 (802.3bm-2015), which uses 12 fibers (MPO-12).